# Computing a recursive function

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question that is:

$a_1 = 1, a_{k+1} = (k+1)+a_k$

compute $a_8$

I suspect $a_8 = 46$

> from:
>     $${a_2 = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3}$$
>       $${a_3 = 2 + 1 + 3 = 6}$$
>       $$...$$

Am I computing this correctly?

Thanks

Comment: I suspect $a_8 = 36$,
Do you mean $a_1 = 1, a_{k+1} = (k+1)+ a_k$?

Comment: If the difference between $\large a_{k + 1}$ and $\large a_{k}$ is $\large k + 1$, the obvious solution is $\large a_{k} = \sum_{n = 1}^{k}n = k\left(k + 1\right)/2 +\ $ $\large\tt\mbox{a constant}$ which is $\large 0$ since $\large a_{1} = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are on the right track, but you made a mistake somewhere:

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
a_{2}&=&(1+1)+1=3\\
a_{3}&=&(2+1)+3=6\\
a_{4}&=&(3+1)+6=10\\
a_{5}&=&(4+1)+10=15\\
a_{6}&=&(5+1)+15=21\\
a_{7}&=&(6+1)+21=28\\
a_{8}&=&(7+1)+28=36\\
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 0):

These are the triangular numbers. It is fairly simple to show that A(k) = k(K+1)/2